# ADFS error - domain name change

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, adfs

I'm currently changing the name of a website that I have developed with in Visual studio. I have updated the DNS and i have changed the site name on IIS(site bindings). Im currently getting an ADFS error. Which i'm presuming is got something to do with authentication? 
The following is my web.config file. The new name for the website is'TechnologySupport'.

[image]

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://adfs.tech.com/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml" />
    **<add key="ida:Realm" value="https://website.tech.com/" />
    <add key="ida:AudienceUri" value="https://website.tech.com/"** />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="Account">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Form/Form">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
      <!--<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/ErrorMessages/Error" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
        <error statusCode="401" redirect="/ErrorMessage/Error"/>
      </customErrors>-->
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="ReExport/ReExport">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization>
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="4.5" maxQueryStringLength="32768" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <!--<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />-->
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      **<audienceUris>
        <add value="https://website.tech.com/" />
      </audienceUris>**
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
        <authority name="http://adfs.tech.com/adfs/services/trust">
          <keys>

          </keys>
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="http://adfs.tech.com/adfs/services/trust" />
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      **<wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://adfs.tech.com/adfs/ls/" realm="https://website.tech.com/" requireHttps="true" />**
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see most likely has nothing to do with your app configuration but rather with the configuration **at the ADFS side**.

Specifically, your website is registered as so called **relying party** there. You should consult the configuration and replace values of both **site identitier** and **ws-federation passive endpoint** to a new value pointing to your new address.

A detailed tutorial that shows the configuration:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/card/2010/06/24/using-federation-metadata-to-establish-a-relying-party-trust-in-ad-fs-2-0/

When your site redirects to ADFS, it identifies itself by appending either its id or endpoint or both:

```
 https://adfs.site/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=yourappid&wreply=https://yourapppassiveendpoint
```

While the two **do not match with values stored in ADFS config**, you will always get this error message.

Comment: One too many negatives in that last sentence, I feel. Or substitute "While" for "Until". Unless you're saying the error will go away once they've established a non-matching config.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: thanks, corrected that. Double negation is native in my language so that I have to pay attention when writing/speaking in english.